# Spring Hadoop Samples Mapreduce throw auxService:mapreduce_shuffle exception

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-data-hadoop

I am following spring hadoop samples [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples) and after trying to run it under mapReduce project:

```
$ mvn clean package

$ sh ./target/appassembler/bin/wordcount
```

I got this error:

```
17:42:55,067  INFO doop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl: 174 - Submitted application application_1433091289740_0003 to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032
17:42:55,095  INFO          org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job:1272 - The url to track the job: http://http://SJCC02MT0NUFD58.local:8088/proxy/application_1433091289740_0003/
17:42:55,096  INFO          org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job:1317 - Running job: job_1433091289740_0003
17:43:15,269  INFO          org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job:1338 - Job job_1433091289740_0003 running in uber mode : false
17:43:15,271  INFO          org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job:1345 -  map 0% reduce 0%
17:43:16,306  INFO          org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job:1424 - Task Id : attempt_1433091289740_0003_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Container launch failed for container_1433091289740_0003_01_000002 : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

I can run hadoop commands, such as: `hdfs dfs -ls , hdfs dfs -put....,` also I can visit: `http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-datanode`

But why this exception happened?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following on yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  </property>
```